# Dashed borders of my window manager (XFce)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, window-manager, xfce4

I upgraded to the latest Xubuntu 13.03 and sometimes borders of my windows (regardless the application) become strangely dashed. I managed to make a screenshot:

[image]

The screenshot is with [Clearlooks-Phenix theme](http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/clearlooks-phenix.php), but the issue is not theme-dependent. I tried multiple themes including the default one for Xubuntu and these dashed borders still appear.

Dashes appear and disappear - they are not permanent. It's annoying. Does anyone know why such dashing appears and how to fix it?

---

**Update:** Adding my compositor settings:

[image: Compositor]

Comment: Do you have display compositing enabled? (Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > top check box.)

Comment: @khamer, good question. Yes. I added my settings above.

Answer (score 2):

(Originally posted by `user226952` at [Dashed borders of my window manager (XFce) - Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394287/dashed-borders-of-my-window-manager-xfce-solution).)

I ran into the same problem as posted here and I found out that the problem only exists on my Intel video laptops (Nvidia was fine) and occurred only with themes having window borders with more than 1px width.

My solution was to create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the content :

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

This switches off sandy bridge acceleration and turns back to slower but reliable `uxa` acceleration.