# Dashed borders of my window manager (XFce) - Solution

Tags: themes, intel-graphics, xfce

I ran into the same problem as posted here [Dashed borders of my window manager (XFce)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312986/dashed-borders-of-my-window-manager-xfce)

I now found a solution but am not able to aswer due to my newbie state.

I found out that the problem only exists on my Intel video laptops (nvidia was fine) and occured only with themes having window borders with more than 1px width.

My solution was to create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the content :

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

This switches off sandy bridge acceleration and turns back to slower but reliable `uxa` acceleration.

Comment: This fix works on my Dell Inspiron 7537 with Linux Mint 16 Xfce